# How can I use name of a conversation as a trigger to start a conversation instead using index?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Inside the manager script I have a method that start a dialogue name : StartDialogue:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class DialogueManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text dialogueText;
    public Text nameText;
    public float sentencesSwitchDuration;
    public bool animateSentenceChars = false;
    public GameObject canvas;
    public static bool dialogueEnded = false;
    public DialogueTrigger trigger;

    private Queue<string> sentence;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        sentence = new Queue<string>();
    }

    public void StartDialogue(Dialogue dialogue)
    {
        canvas.SetActive(true);

        nameText.text = dialogue.name;

        sentence.Clear();
        foreach (string sentence in dialogue.sentences)
        {
            this.sentence.Enqueue(sentence);
        }

        DisplayNextSentence();
    }

    public void DisplayNextSentence()
    {
        if (this.sentence.Count == 0)
        {
            EndDialogue();
            return;
        }

        string sentence = this.sentence.Dequeue();
        dialogueText.text = sentence;

        StopAllCoroutines();
        StartCoroutine(DisplayNextSentenceWithDelay(sentence));
    }

    public IEnumerator DisplayNextSentenceWithDelay(string sentence)
    {
        if (animateSentenceChars)
        {
            dialogueText.text = "";
            foreach (char letter in sentence.ToCharArray())
            {
                dialogueText.text += letter;
                yield return null;
            }
        }

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(sentencesSwitchDuration);
        DisplayNextSentence();
    }

    private void EndDialogue()
    {
        dialogueEnded = true;
        if (trigger.dialogueNum == trigger.conversations[trigger.dialogueIndex].Dialogues.Count)
            canvas.SetActive(false);
        Debug.Log("End of conversation.");
    }
}
```

Then in the trigger script I have a method name TriggerDialogue that get index number. For example index 0 it will start the dialoue/s of the first conversation. But in fact it's just starting the first dialogue from the dialogues List.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class DialogueTrigger : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<Conversation> conversations = new List<Conversation>();
    //public List<Dialogue> dialogue = new List<Dialogue>();

    [HideInInspector]
    public int dialogueNum = 0;

    [HideInInspector]
    public int dialogueIndex = 0;

    private bool triggered = false;
    private List<Dialogue> oldDialogue;
    private bool activateButton = false;

    public void TriggerDialogue(int dialogueIndex)
    {
        this.dialogueIndex = dialogueIndex;

        if (conversations.Count > 0 &&
            conversations[dialogueIndex].Dialogues.Count > 0)
        {
            if (triggered == false)
            {
                if (FindObjectOfType<DialogueManager>() != null)
                {
                    FindObjectOfType<DialogueManager>().StartDialogue(conversations[dialogueIndex].Dialogues[dialogueNum]);
                    dialogueNum += 1;
                }
                triggered = true;
            }
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        ButtonActivation();

        if (DialogueManager.dialogueEnded == true)
        {
            if (dialogueNum == conversations[dialogueIndex].Dialogues.Count)
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                FindObjectOfType<DialogueManager>().StartDialogue(conversations[dialogueIndex].Dialogues[dialogueNum]);
                DialogueManager.dialogueEnded = false;
                dialogueNum += 1;
            }
        }
    }

    public bool ActivateButton()
    {
        return activateButton;
    }

    private void ButtonActivation()
    {
        if (ConversationsChecks() == true)
        {
            foreach (string sentence in conversations[dialogueIndex].Dialogues[dialogueNum].sentences)
            {
                if (sentence != "")
                {
                    activateButton = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    activateButton = false;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            activateButton = false;
        }
    }

    public void SaveConversations()
    {
        string jsonTransform = JsonHelper.ToJson(conversations.ToArray(), true);
        File.WriteAllText(@"d:\json.txt", jsonTransform);
    }

    public void LoadConversations()
    {
        string jsonTransform = File.ReadAllText(@"d:\json.txt");
        conversations.Clear();
        conversations.AddRange(JsonHelper.FromJson<Conversation>(jsonTransform));
    }

    private bool ConversationsChecks()
    {
        bool IsConversationsReady = false;

        if (conversations.Count > 0 &&
            conversations[dialogueIndex].Dialogues.Count > 0 &&
            conversations[dialogueIndex].Dialogues[dialogueNum].sentences.Count > 0 &&
            conversations[dialogueIndex].Dialogues[dialogueNum].name != "" &&
            conversations[dialogueIndex].name != "")
        {
            IsConversationsReady = true;
        }
        else
        {
            IsConversationsReady = false;
        }

        return IsConversationsReady;
    }
}
```

Then I have more two small classes :

Dialogue:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[System.Serializable]
public class Dialogue
{
    [Tooltip("Dialogue Name")]
    public string name;

    [TextArea(1, 10)]
    public List<string> sentences = new List<string>();
}
```

And Conversation :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[System.Serializable]
public class Conversation
{
    [Tooltip("Conversation Name")]
    public string name;

    public List<Dialogue> Dialogues = new List<Dialogue>();
}
```

So now when I want to start a dialogue I'm calling the TriggerDialogue method like this example :

```
dialogueTrigger.TriggerDialogue(0);
```

Instead I want to do something like that :

```
dialogueTrigger.StartConversation("Opening Scene");
```

Or

```
dialogueTrigger.StartConversation("The last conversation");
```

And this is example screenshot of how the Inspector of the conversations and dialogues looks like :

[Conversations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kulXv.jpg)

So if for example I want to start the first conversation somewhere in my game I will do :

```
dialogueTrigger.StartConversation("The Opening");
```

And it will start the dialogue/s inside the "The Opening" conversation.

Using the index is working fine but I want to use to start a conversation by the conversation name it will be easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you are using a `List<T>`, if you move away from using the index to get the item you want, you will need to enumerate the collection each time to find that same item. The best you can do here, is change the data structure to a `Dictionary`, so you can search for it by the Key and avoid the performance hit. In order to also avoid having to remember what names you put to the conversations, perhaps it would be best to use an Enum.

So, create the enum:

```
public enum SceneConversations
{
    OpeningScene = 1,
    // ...
}
```

and start using

```
public class DialogueTrigger : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Dictionary<SceneConversations, Conversation> conversations = new Dictionary<SceneConversations, Conversation>();
```

you can then use

```
public void StartConversation(SceneConversations conversationWanted) {}
```

and call it with

```
dialogueTrigger.StartConversation(SceneConversations.OpeningScene);
```

If I remember correctly, this has the added advantage that Unity will show you a drop-down for the possible values of SceneConversations, so that's also easier to handle.

Comment: Since in the script DialogueTrigger I'm using [ExecuteInEditMode] I have the items already in the conversations List for example if I will type in the script: conversations[0].name it will give me the first conversation name "The Opening" So I wonder if there is a way instead creating my own enum to use the already items in the conversations List ? Since I give each conversation the name in the inspector the names are already in the List.

Comment: @yochile Well, as you said, you are using `conversations[0].name`, so you are using the index to get the name. You would have to loop through the items in that way